# Nodes selection inside HtmlNodeCollection with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack, xmlnode

I have html structure like that:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <a href="test" title="professional and enthusiast programmers">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <a href="test" title="professional and enthusiast programmers">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to select all nodes with class1:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,' class1 ')]");
```

And select all nodes inside that node which contains class2:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
   HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = node.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,' class2 ')]");
}
```

But nodes2 gets class2 from all nodes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='class1']");

var nodes2 = nodes.Select(c1 => c1.SelectNodes("div[@class='class2']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative XPath worked for me

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='class1']");
var nodes2 = nodes.Select(c1 => c1.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='class2']"));
```